# Can advisor list a former PhD student, who changed advisors, in his/her CV?

Tags: phd, advisor, cv

I found that my former PhD advisor was still listing me as his student and he was the chair of my committee. I changed advisors a few years ago and left him. He didn't remain in my committee. It is true that he was my advisor to that point. But I feel it's not fair to my current advisor, who actually supported me and guided me to dissertation and graduation. Since I didn't graduate under the former one, my name doesn't have graduation year in his CV, which looks like I dropped out. If a professor was an advisor of a student at some point, can he list the student as his student forever?

Comment: In what way is he "listing you as his student"? In a CV? On a website? On a presentation slide?

Comment: In what way is it not fair? If you were his PhD student, it's fine if he lists you as such. That says nothing about the quality of the supervision - if people are interested in that, they will have to ask you.

Comment: Maybe he just hasn't updated his CV in a while...

Comment: You seem interested in devaluing the labor of this professor in being your advisor. There were probably good reasons for you to switch, but that does not mean your former advisor devalues the labor they invested in being your advisor.

Comment: I've never heard of listing students on a CV!

Comment: @Alexis Sorry for this two month late comment. I appreciate your feedback. I just wanted to make it clear that my intention was not to 'devalue' other person's labor. That was the reason why I struggled and pondered about the change for a year. There were serious academic issues, and that's why I was surprised that he was still listing me as his student.  To everyone in the academia - in the future, when a student raises questions about his/her advisor's behavior, please do not assume the intention is negative - getting back, devaluing, etc. The student might have suffered enough.

Answer (score 22):

TL;DR: Yes, he can.

He can list you; probably he'll hide that you left him, but who cares?

You graduated and whenever you apply, your CV will show that. Nobody will check *his* CV for *your* graduation.

Theodor Fontane (a German novelist) famously said, "Happiness is a good stomach and a bad memory." Forget about him and care about your future.

Comment: In addition, I've seen people on this site (probably a minority) express the opinion that leaving something like that off a CV would be dishonest.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist True, but I think nobody would really care, unless this is a regular occurrence and in the latter case, this is a problem for the department more than the prof's CV.

Comment: That is a great quote. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This just isn't a situation you need to worry about at all.  No one is going to notice or care that you're listed on this CV, and if they do they'll just assume the CV is out-of-date.  Your former advisor isn't getting any meaningful benefits from listing you, so fairness isn't an issue.  One extra student isn't a big deal, and furthermore during serious evaluation more detail would be given.  For example, when I'm evaluated for raises there's separate sections for current Ph.D. candidates, for graduated students, and for reading courses supervised.  A former student who switched advisors would "count" under that last category but not the former ones.

Answer (score 7):

> If a professor was an advisor of a student at some point, can he list the student as his student forever?

Depends what you mean by “list”. If he does it in a way that creates a misleading impression that you graduated under his supervision, then no, that’s dishonest and obviously unacceptable.

If he just lists you in a section titled “Students” or “Students mentored” and you are mentioned there with no specifics, then it’s fine, that is a factually correct representation and I don’t see why you should complain or care. Be thankful for the mentorship you received from him, and be even more thankful you ended up with someone who was a better fit for you and who isn’t so insecure that they need to pad their CV with pointless fluff about people they helped in some not very significant way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want. From the title, it seems like you want to know that if a professor can list in his CV his former student who left him. In this case, I find nothing wrong with listing you as a "former PhD student".

However, from your text, you think the way he list you damages your reputation (I might be interpreting this wrongly). This is because listing you without an graduation year could implies that you are a "drop-out".

I feel what you felt. If I was you, I would email my previous advisor's assistant asking him to either **add a graduation year**, or remove me from his student list, or **specify that I transferred to another group**. I think all of these three requests are reasonable.

Any comments, long or short, are welcome if you find my interpretation or my suggestion wrong.

---

So in sum, I think listing previous student is a grey area: to list and to not list, both are reasonable. There are a lot of professors list no student on his website or CV. One similar case is can you list someone who commented your paper or your idea in the acknowledgement list? I think by default, you could always acknowledge him, but not necessarily unless he did help you a lot or he asked you. Even if he contributed a lot, he still has the right to ask you to remove his name.

Comment: Didn't downvote, as there are some good points. However, I wouldn't mail him. OP left the supervisor for a reason. Keep away from people you do not want in your life.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I personally know several cases when a PhD student changed their advisor. One was because the former advisor changed their research direction, and the other one or two for some weird reason assumably related to writing and defending their theses, even though their advisor told them they are ready to graduate.

Comment: @Jake True, indeed. However, OP does seem to begrudge the old supervisor them being listed, so that indicates some less wholesome situation.